# What spell did they use to kill the Obscurus?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, obscurus

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, what spell did the MACUSA Aurors use to destroy the Obscurus?

Comment: *Did* they, now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a wide array of *offensive* spells. No specific ones are mentioned in the screenplay.

> SCENE 116 - INT. SUBWAY—NIGHT
>
> Aurors continue to aim spells at the Obscurus, their efforts
> unrelenting and brutal.
>
> Under this pressure, the Obscurus finally seems to implode – a white
> ball of magical light taking over from the black mass.
>
> The force of the change sends TINA, NEWT and the Aurors stumbling
> backwards.
>
> <sub><sup>[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fantastic-Beasts-Where-Find-Them/dp/1408708981)</sup></sub>

Comment: Just generic movie spells.

Comment: @ibid - Yup. One of the things I found frustrating about this film is that the spellcasting was so generic. Basically just pointing and shooting.

Comment: Isn't that all the HP films?

Comment: @ibid - This was the worst.

Comment: And sometimes just hand motions without even pointing a wand.